# Query returns unwanted results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables "Dispatch" and "Salesled" that contains the relational column Invoice. "SalesLed" has multiple records relating to 1 specific invoice number. Dispatch has only 1 result. I need the query to return the invoice only if all the matches for Spiff in "Salesled" are zero. Otherwise, I do not want to see that invoice.

---

**Basic Query:**

```
SELECT invoice,dispatch
  FROM dispatch
 WHERE Invoice=0000001071
```

[image]

```
SELECT invoice,spiff
  FROM salesled
 WHERE Invoice=0000001071
```

[image]

---

**Undesired Result:** It returns the invoice with the 2 records.

```
SELECT SalesLed.Invoice, SalesLed.Spiff, Dispatch.Dispatch
  FROM   Dispatch
 INNER JOIN SalesLed
    ON Dispatch.Invoice = SalesLed.Invoice
 WHERE dispatch.Dispatch = 50007
```

[image]

**Desired Result:** I want it to return no invoices since one of the results has a spiff larger than 0. I am wondering if there is a simple function I don't know about that would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `NOT EXISTS` clause will do the trick:

```
select d.*
  from Dispatch d
 where d.Invoice = 50007
   and not exists (select *
                    from SalesLed s
                   where s.Invoice = d.Invoice
                     and s.spiff > 0)
```

My query assumes that you're not actually interested in displaying the value for `SalesLed.Spiff`, since it would always come back `0` anyways, if I understand your data correctly.

Comment: Awesome stuff. I was able to use it and get the results I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesLed.Invoice, max(SalesLed.Spiff), Dispatch.Dispatch

FROM Dispatch INNER JOIN SalesLed ON Dispatch.Invoice = SalesLed.Invoice

WHERE dispatch.Dispatch = 50007 group by SalesLed.Invoice,Dispatch.Dispatch

having max(SalesLed.Spiff)<=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (select invoice from SalesLed where spiff = 0 
           except
           select invoice from SalesLed where spiff > 0)
SELECT S.Invoice, S.Spiff, D.Dispatch
FROM Dispatch d 
INNER JOIN SalesLed s on D.Invoice = S.Invoice
INNER JOIN x on x.invoice = s.invoice
```

You can use a `cte` to first select all the invoices from salesled table where all the spiffs for a invoice are = 0. Then use it in the original query to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cross apply as follows;

```
select
      i.[invoice] as [Invoice]
    , s.[mspiff] as [Spiff]
    , i.[dispatch] as [Dispatch]
from [invoice] i
cross apply
    ( select isnull(max(spiff),0) as [mspiff] from [salesled] where [Invoice] = i.[Invoice]) s
where s.[mspiff] = 0
```

With several answers you can see which performs best for your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SELECT SalesLed.Invoice, SalesLed.Spiff, Dispatch.Dispatch
FROM Dispatch INNER JOIN SalesLed ON Dispatch.Invoice = SalesLed.Invoice
WHERE dispatch.Dispatch = 50007 AND SalesLed.Spiff > 0
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or only provided part of the solution you had in mind, this will return the rows with Spiff values greater than zero but the op wants no rows when this condition exists.